# angular error: $http.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to post file on my server as soon as it will get attached with directve so I did api call but I got this error while doing. I don't know where am i going wrong

**here is my code**

```
app.directive('fileModel',fileupload);

fileupload.$inject =  ['$http','$parse']; 

function fileupload ($http,$parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,$http) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function($http){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('file', element[0].files[0]);
                    fd.append('id', user_id);
                    var uploadUrl = "https://******/routes/contactRoute.php?action=upload";
                    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                    }).
                    then(function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                      }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `$http` from `link` function. it is not needed

```
app.directive('fileModel',fileupload);

fileupload.$inject =  ['$http','$parse']; 

function fileupload ($http,$parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function($http){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('file', element[0].files[0]);
                    fd.append('id', user_id);
                    var uploadUrl = "https://******/routes/contactRoute.php?action=upload";
                    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                    }).
                    then(function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                      }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Edit 1: You also need to remove `$http` from `$apply` callback. You don't need to pass $http to any other internal function. It has been already injected and available for all other internal methods.

```
scope.$apply(function(){}
```

Comment: Still same error @Ved $http.post is not a function
    at summaryController.js:19

Comment: @ved answer should also work but needs some tweaking and verifying. Check my answer - notice $http removed from the $scope.apply as well

Comment: Thanks @Ved . you made my day.

Comment: @sameerdighe Welcome. Happy to help.